# How to setup relationship in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now i have created methods like this..

```
class TestMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test
    Test.find(:first,:conditions => ["test_uri = ?",self.sfl_test_uri])
  end
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test_messages
    TestMessage.find(:all,:conditions => ["sfl_test_uri = ?",self.test_uri])
  end
end
```

How may i convert it into relationship ?

Comment: [Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class TestMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test, :foreign_key => :sfl_test_uri, :primary_key => :test_uri
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_messages, :foreign_key => :sfl_test_uri, :primary_key => :test_uri
end
```

Comment: Can I use :joins and :include both together with this relationship ? TestMessage.find(:all,:joins => :test,:include => :test)

Comment: Just include it: TestMessage.includes(:test) and test will be eager loaded… No need to join…